# Differences between ORM model and Database table

Tags: python, sql, sqlalchemy

I'm learning about Databases (Postgres) and ORM, and be blocked by this.

In the database, I have something like this

```
CREATE TABLE public.city (
    city_id    serial PRIMARY KEY,
    city_name  varchar(50) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    region_id  integer NOT NULL REFERENCES public.region ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

And, in my Flask app (python, Flask microframework, and Flask-SqlAlchemy) model definition I have:

```
class City(Base):
    city_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    city_name = db.Column(
        db.String(50),
        unique=True,
        nullable=False)
    region_id = db.Column(
        db.Integer,
        db.ForeignKey(
            'region.region_id',
            ondelete="CASCADE"),
        nullable=False)

    country = db.relationship(
        'Region',
        backref=db.backref('cities'))
```

My doubt is: Is all this `unique` and `nullable` necessary in my python model? Considering that the database table is created from an SQL script file and not by SqlAlchemy.

This information adds something usable to the ORM framework?

Comment: try to remove them and see what happens

Comment: You'll probably run into many problems if these two get out of synch. Ultimately if you are going to use an ORM to handle your application, you should use it to manage the database. Youll get hurt by the ORM is the schema does nto match the model.
Speaking of your data model, do you think its a good idea to make a city name unique? There is more than one Charleston in the USA. There's more than one Cuba in the world. If you think you must have this, try a composite unique constraint on State and City.

Comment: @DavidButtrick The database is handled by another team member, so I just need to connect to it and use it, therefore my doubt. About the "composite unique constraint", I will check it out. Thanks!

Comment: nullable is by default False you need to specify nullable=True wherever required. At least in Postgres it works in this way